# Does Zhang's result on primes makes RSA weaker?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I read from Finnish newspaper ( http://www.uusisuomi.fi/tiede-ja-ymparisto/72212-matemaattinen-ongelma-eli-2-300-vuotta-mies-subway-tiskin-takaa-ratkaisi#.VBwhYp09F2k.facebook ) the article of Zhang's results that there are infinitely many prime pairs $(p_1,p_2)$ where $p_2-p_1=70000000$ the following:

Zhang's breakthrough made cracking the RSA-cryptography a bit easier. In reality, RSA is still a strong protection, and one gets million dollar prize if one cracks it.

Is this RSA-part true? I guess there is one mistake and it should be that $0<p_2-p_1\leq 70000000$.

Comment: Can you give a link to the article in question? I am not a number theorist but I don't see how it makes sense. For one thing, it is an asymptotic result and doesn't seem to say anything about primes in the range we normally use for RSA.

Comment: I can give link but can you read Finnish?

Comment: "Zhang's breakthrough made cracking the RSA-cryptography a bit easier" - in what way (how did it make RSA cracking easier)? Everybody assumes that there are infinitely many primes of gap $2$ anyway. What would be the contribution of having a full proof to the fact that there are infinitely many primes of gap $7$ million???

Comment: There was an episode of Elementary http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_%28TV_series%29 in which a murder occurred because the victim had a proof of P = NP or the like, and that this would be worth billions.. people will say anything. Found the episode http://www.tv.com/shows/elementary/community/post/elementary-solve-for-x-review-season-2-episode-2--138084402962/

Comment: @WillJagy possibly still closer there is a  Numbers episode where somebody is close to proving Riemann Hypothesis and  then "would be able" to break RSA. (Now there are some actual relations around there, but for practice of factorization a proof is typically irrelevant...if it worked it worked.) Added: It is season 1, episode 5.

Comment: @quid, I found Numbers painful to watch, stopped. There was a short interview with the woman consulting on mathematics for the show, faculty near L.A.; she said how they would give her a script with truly odious mathematics talk, she would suggest slightly less horrible stuff, rarely was able to sway them much. Trying to remember the name of the college, started with O i think.

Comment: Seems they had several consultants...Could have been Alice Silverberg at Irvine, short piece about her http://planetmath.org/numb3rs and the show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result proves what everybody expected anyway. If one wants to crack something you can assume whatever seems reasonable (oversimplifying a bit). The claim seems dubious or imprecise at best.

*Added:* I just had a look at that article (to be precise, an automatic translation of it). It does not say much specific and I really think it can be ignored. For one thing, nowhere are the key-sizes made precise for RSA being broken or being still save and so on. This is a huge red-flag as with too short keys RSA is completely unsafe. Thus the claim does not mean much at all.

Further to claims, for good balance a claim is made that the Petangon (whatever this is supposed to mean precisely) might or might not be able to crack RSA.

In sum, I would not pay much attention to the math content of that article.